Populate data in Edit Popup and Update data in database as well as HTML Table
I want to Update data in my database and show it in html table too using php. Just a beginner, so code is quite messy :)
My Code for the the web page from where I want to update is:
<?php

require '../connect.php';

// ADD COURSE

if (isset($_POST['addCourse'])) {
    $courseName = $_POST['courseName'];
    $semesters = $_POST['semesters'];

    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO courses(course_name, semester) VALUES('$courseName', '$semesters')";
    if ($conn->query($insertQuery) == TRUE) {

        header("location: course.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error:" . $conn->error;
    }
}

// SHOW COURSE IN TABLE

$showData = " SELECT * FROM courses";
$result = $conn->query($showData);

// DELETE COURSE

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM `courses` WHERE id = '$id'";
    $run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if ($run) {
        header('location:course.php');
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <script defer src="../JS/script.js"></script>
    <script defer src="../JS/popupedit.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <title>Question Paper Generator</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h2>admin</h2>


            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="./dashboard.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>Dashboard</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="./course.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-graduation-cap"></i>Course</a></div>
            <div class="item">
                <a class="sub-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i>Subject<i class="fa-solid ar fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <a href="./add_sub.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>Add Subject</a>
                    <a href="./add_sub_unit.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>Add Subject Unit</a>
                    <a href="./manage_sub.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>Manage Subject</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><a class="sub-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-question"></i>Question<i class="fa-solid ar fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                <div class="submenu">

                    <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>Set Question</a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>Manage Question</a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><a class="sub-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-clipboard-question"></i>Question Paper
                    Generator<i class="fa-solid ar fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <a href="./set_paper.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>Set Paper</a>
                    <a href="./manage_paper.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>Manage Paper</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="item"><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>Profile</a></div> -->
            <div class="item"><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-from-bracket"></i>Log Out</a></div>

        </div>

        <div class="main_content">
            <div class="header"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i> QUESTION PAPER GENERATOR</div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="section2">

        <div class="right">
            <h1>Manage Course</h1>
        </div>

        <button class="course_button" onclick="openPopup()">Add Course</button>

        <!-- POPUP -->

        <div class="overlay" id="overlay" style="display: none;"></div>

        <form class="popup" id="coursePopup" style="display: none;" method="post">

            <p>Add Course</p>
            <div class="pp-ele">
                <label for="course-name"><b>Course Name</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="course-name" placeholder="Enter Course Name" name="courseName" required>
            </div>
            <div class="pp-ele">
                <label for="sem"><b>Semester</b></label>
                <select id="sem" name="semesters"">
                    <option value="No Semester">No Semester</option>
                    <option value="1st Semester">1st Semester</option>
                    <option value="2nd Semester">2nd Semester</option>
                    <option value="3rd Semester">3rd Semester</option>
                    <option value="4th Semester">4th Semester</option>
                    <option value="5th Semester">5th Semester</option>
                    <option value="6th Semester">6th Semester</option>
                    <option value="7th Semester">7th Semester</option>
                    <option value="8th Semester">8th Semester</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="pp-ele-btn">
                <button onclick="closePopup()" id="close-btn">Close</button>
                <button id="sv-chng" name="addCourse">Add Course</button>
            </div>

        </form>

        <!-- EDIT POPUP -->
        
        <form class="popup" id="courseEditPopup" style="display: none;" method="post">
            <p>Edit Course</p>
            <div class="pp-ele">
                <label for="course-name"><b>Course Name</b></label>
                
                <input type="text" id="course-name" placeholder="Enter Course Again" name="courseNameEdit" required>
            </div>
            <div class="pp-ele">
                <label for="sem"><b>Semester</b></label>
                <select id="sem" name="semestersEdit"">
                    <option value="No Semester">No Semester</option>
                    <option value="1st Semester">1st Semester</option>
                    <option value="2nd Semester">2nd Semester</option>
                    <option value="3rd Semester">3rd Semester</option>
                    <option value="4th Semester">4th Semester</option>
                    <option value="5th Semester">5th Semester</option>
                    <option value="6th Semester">6th Semester</option>
                    <option value="7th Semester">7th Semester</option>
                    <option value="8th Semester">8th Semester</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="pp-ele-btn">
                <button onclick="closeEditPopup()" id="close-btn">Close</button>
                <button id="sv-chng" name="editCourse">Save Changes</button>
            </div>

        </form>
        


        <!-- DATA TABLE -->

        <div class="container">
            <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Course name</th>
                        <th>Semester</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $i = 1;
                    if ($num = mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>" . $i++ . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $row['course_name'] . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $row['semester'] . "</td>
                                        <td>
                                            
                                            <button class='edit-btn' onclick='openEditPopup()'><i class='fa-solid fa-pen-to-square'></i> Edit</button>
                                            
                                            <a href='course.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'><button class='dlt-btn' name='deleteCourse'><i class='fa-solid fa-trash'></i> Delete</button></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                ";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>


I want My popup to be opened where i can edit and it should be on the course page itself while fetching details in the input tag of the popup so as to edit.
My JS code for the edit popup is:
function openEditPopup() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
  var popup = document.getElementById("courseEditPopup");

  overlay.style.display = "block";
  popup.style.display = "block";

  setTimeout(function () {
    overlay.style.opacity = "1";
    popup.style.opacity = "1";
    popup.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)";
  }, 10); // Small delay to trigger the CSS transition
}

function closeEditPopup() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
  var popup = document.getElementById("courseEditPopup");

  overlay.style.opacity = "0";
  popup.style.opacity = "0";
  popup.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.8)";

  setTimeout(function () {
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    popup.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("course-name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("sem").selectedIndex = 0;
  }, 300); // Wait for the transition to complete before hiding
}

And page looks like this:
Course Page
And this is popup where i want to populate and then save the updated changes in DB and HTML table after i click on "SAVE CHANGES".
Edit Popup
What is the Soln for this?
I tried watching tutorials and reading articles of updating but none of them worked as i have that Popup where i want to edit.
Also tried Mr ADyson's Suggestion, but could not achieve my goal.

The code you show does not show an UPDATE to a database !

It sounds like your problem is actually about how to show a popup on your page and populate it with the existing recorded data, rather than how to update your database? These are two different tasks. But it's really not very clear. Please revise your question to make it more focused and have a clearer explanation of where you are getting stuck. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Yes You're right! I actually want to populate popup with existing record. Later there is a button of save changes so as to update changes made to those populated data in database. I'll share more details and code. Thanks for pointing out!

Ok. So one basic pattern for such a thing is: 1) define a <div which is initially hidden. This div will contain the editing form. The form fields are all there at the start but they are empty. 2) Each row in your table needs an "edit" button. Each button should have a data-attribute in its HTML which contains the unique ID of the record it's related to, and also a CSS class it shares with all the other edit buttons. 3) add a JavaScript event listener which handles clicks on all the edit buttons (you can select them all by the shared class)...

...the event handler JS code would get the record ID from the data-attribute of the clicked button. 4) The JS then sends an AJAX request to a PHP script on your server and sends the record ID with it. The server sends back all the data for that record, in a structured format (e.g. JSON). 5) The JS populates the edit form with the values returned by the server for each field, and then shows the editing div. 6) the editing form has a Submit button - when this is clicked it submits the form to the server, so a PHP script can update the edited data in the database.

FYI: Nesting button into a, or vice versa, is not allowed in HTML.

I changed my Question as i was not able to solve the issue. So any suggestions!

Did you try any of things I suggested in my solution outline from a few days ago (in the comments above)? None of the code you've posted appears to attempt to implement any of it

Yeah I did try.. But since i wasn't able to Update it, I removed the code and sent the above code so that any expertise could solve from start. And actually i tried solving by your way till halfway, then i just couldn't comprehend steps so took help from Chat GPT! Then also Update wasn't achieved.. :)

Yeah chatGPT doesn't know how to program! I can sometimes speed up simpler tasks if you already know what you're doing, but you can't ask it to replace your lack of knowledge - it will give you code, but it usually contains silly mistakes or nonsense, so you need to be able to double-check everything it gives you. You cannot simply copy and paste what it tells you, without understanding it!

sent the above code so that any expertise could solve from start...ok but that's not what we do at Stackoverflow. We're not a free write-my-code service. We'll help you with a specific problem within your attempt to solve it. So please show us your best effort so far and explain exactly where it went wrong. Then we can help to fix your particular issue, or maybe finish the job for you if you got most of the way there. Reminder: [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue. "I have no idea what to do so please code the whole thing for me" isn't a programming question.
